# Form action overriding onClick function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with buttons in it and when you click on the button it is supposed to do two things, 1. post the button value which displays an element on the screen and 2. trigger some JS so that a second element will appear on the screen. The element that is supposed to appear with the onClick event pops up for a split second but then disappears while the element that is supposed to appear as a result of the post stays the whole time.

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <button 
        onclick="showDowntown()" 
        name="departmentbutton"
        type="submit" 
        value="601"
    >
        601
    </button>
```

```
function showDowntown() {
    var x = document.getElementById("Downtown");

    if (x.style.display === "") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're submitting your form. You need to prevent that event. Try changing `type="submit" ` to `type="button" `

Comment: That is probably because the page is reloading to post the value to the page, which is resetting the Downtown display. Consider using jquery Ajax, to post to the page without reloading.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @j08691, the default action for buttons of type `submit` is to submit the form on click. So OP will have to prevent the default action from happening, in JavaScript

Comment: @j08691 The problem with that is that I need to submit the form data so that the value tag can be used in PHP to search a database and display results. If I change the type to button it will no longer do that.

Comment: You can have it both way unless you use AJAX to pass the form data to a script on the server to update your DB. Submitting your form will reload your page unless you stop it.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for the assistance, I'm not too familiar with AJAX so if I could avoid it that would be preferable. Would it be possible for me to delay the onClick event until after the page has been reloaded by the form?

Comment: No. Once the page reloads, all of your code changes are lost.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'll take you and Studowho's advice and try with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-formaction

The URL that processes the information submitted by the button. Overrides the action attribute of the button's form owner. Does nothing if there is no form owner.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the value with id through getdocumentbyid("id").value and use javascript to submit the form by using the id of the form like this ("formid").submit()
Don't forget to remove the button type =submit